# CPanel - addon domain with greek TLD .ελ

Tags: cpanel, tld, addon-domain

I try to addon a domain via `cpanel` with the new greek TLD `.ελ`. (It does contain greek characters).

Ι am going to

```
cpanel > domains > Addon Domains
```

and in the first input "New Domain Name", when I add the new domain (eg: `mydomain.ελ`), I get the error:

> That is not a valid domain.

Ι think the problem is with the greek characters in the TLD.
Are these `cpanel` issues?
Or is this a server configuration issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find more help here: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

In case of IDNs many tools are not updated to handle them and need to manipulate the encode form.

So in your case try to use `xn--qxam` instead as TLD, it should at least be accepted, but other things may not work later on.

If the other part of the domain has non ASCII characters too, you will need to encode it. Search for IDN encoding or punycode.